# Can I configure maven-compiler-plugin to process .class files instead of .java files?

Tags: java, maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

When I use `javac` on the command line to process annotations on a single class I can do the following:

```
$ javac -proc:only -cp target/classes -sourcepath target/classes x.y.z.Bar
```

I'd like to do the same thing in maven, except using all classes in the *target/classes* directory instead of just specifying one class file. I do not want to specify any java source files (either implicitly or explicitly) because I want to avoid loading and parsing source files multiple times.

Is this possible to configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to load class files only, instead of loading java source files? I tried adding the following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>process-annotations</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Annotation processing only -->
        <proc>only</proc>
        <!-- Include all class files in target/classes directory. -->
        <includes>
          <include>${project.build.outputDirectory}/**/*.class</include>
        </include>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But I see `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date` in the plugin output, and there's no annotation processing performed.

Not sure if this possible, but it would be sweet if so.

**Edit #1**

Actually that `<includes>` option is not right, since `javac -proc:only` accepts class names and not class file names (e.g. *x.y.z.Foo* not *x/y/z/Foo.class*). And I see the following in the plugin output:

```
compileSourceRoots=[..mumble../foo/src/main/java]
```

which I don't think can be changed in the plugin configuration. Does not look promising.

Comment: ...but .class files are already compiled... or am I missed something?

Comment: I have a maven module with over 9000 source files. What happens here is that the default `maven-compiler-plugin` execution (with `proc:none`) parses all  the java files, and then the second execution (with `proc:only`) either parses those source files *again*, or sometimes decides that all source files are up to date and does *nothing*. The `javac` compiler allows annotation processing by specifying class files as input, and I was wondering if the `maven-compiler-plugin` can do the same, so that I can speed up the build process and make it reliable. Hope that helps.

Comment: First why not using an up-to-date version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.1...3.2 is on it's way). Why not let maven plugin do it's work. What would you like to improve? If you are compiling annotation processing can be done with the same run..i really don't understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd like to upgrade to `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.x but that's not an option right now. I typically do compiling + processing in the same run but I am getting major memory issues and one option (among several others) is to try splitting the compiling from the annotation processing, if possible, just as `javac` allows. If that's not possible with `maven-compiler-plugin` (at least for 2.5.1, and I'm not sure that moving to a 3.x version will allow this, either) then I will explore other options (e.g. modifying memory limits, splitting up the module, etc).